# MagicalRecord does not save data after close application from process

Tags: ios, magicalrecord

I have this code that save for me a city I receive from backend and it works perfect for the first time:

```
+ (void)saveCurrentCityWithParameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
                          withSuccess:(OperationCompletionBlock)successBlock
                          withFailure:(OperationFailureBlock)failure
{
    [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {

        KNCity *knCity = [KNCity MR_findFirstInContext:localContext];

        if (!knCity)
        {
            knCity = [KNCity MR_createInContext:localContext];
        }

        knCity.city_id = [NSNumber integerString:parameters[@"id"]];
        knCity.city_lat = [NSNumber doubleString:parameters[@"lat"]];
        knCity.city_lng = [NSNumber doubleString:parameters[@"lng"]];
        knCity.city_name = parameters[@"name"];

    } completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {

        [KNFilterHelper disableAllFilters];

        [self requestFiltersWithSuccess:successBlock
                            withFailure:failure];

    }];
}
```

Second time it also works perfect but in case if app is still running, If I remove from active process, it does not work.

Should I save it?

First time run:

```
(lldb) po localContext
<NSManagedObjectContext: 0x7a351150>


(lldb) po knCity
<KNCity: 0x78fbc960> (entity: KNCity; id: 0x78fb5340 <x-coredata:///KNCity/t2C6E56FF-7DD0-4505-A8A2-974EA687A87A3> ; data: {
    "city_id" = 0;
    "city_lat" = 0;
    "city_lng" = 0;
    "city_name" = nil;
})
```

After first time filling properties

```
(lldb) po knCity
<KNCity: 0x78fbc960> (entity: KNCity; id: 0x78fb5340 <x-coredata:///KNCity/t2C6E56FF-7DD0-4505-A8A2-974EA687A87A3> ; data: {
    "city_id" = 26;
    "city_lat" = "51.151817";
    "city_lng" = "71.480124";
    "city_name" = "\U0410\U0441\U0442\U0430\U043d\U0430";
})
```

After changing a city:

```
(lldb) po localContext
<NSManagedObjectContext: 0x78f8a230>

(lldb) po knCity
<KNCity: 0x78fd37c0> (entity: KNCity; id: 0x78fc1110 <x-coredata://38CD5A19-1361-438E-8FFE-0DC5388B737C/KNCity/p1> ; data: <fault>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without more information, my suggestion would be to check the error object to see if you're data is not validating. When a property is not optional, for example, and you set it to nil, the entire save operation will fail. This will result in the symptoms you are describing, namely that you do not see data between runs of the application.

Comment: So I've checked error is nil, and success is YES. What details do you need, actually this is just one method here )

Comment: I've added a log, seems entry has different id, but I can't understand why?

Comment: this method works good for me even after remove app from active, it save for me all changes, + (void) saveInBackgroundWithBlock:(void(^)(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext))block completion:(void(^)(void))completion __attribute__((deprecated)); but it's deprecated.

Comment: I've updated pods form 2.0.8 to 2.2 and everything works great!

Comment: hm seems it does not help

Comment: can you help, what I do wrong? I've updated pods but still have the issue I've described

Comment: sorry it was my mistake )

Comment: Would you mind answering your own question then so we can know the resolution?

Comment: oh it was my crazy issue. I rewrite my model twice using core location, so automatically detect city for me and re write data model automatically. so it's not connected to magical records or any versions

Comment: we can close question if you remove your answer. I can delete it. thanks so much